# How much are you paid as a mercenary?

Tags: mount-and-blade-warband

A simple question with an elusive answer: if I sign a mercenary contract with a lord, how much will I be paid?

Comment: You tagged two different games, which one is this question about?

Comment: The games are so similar, I did not expect there to be a difference. Most articles on the Mount & Blade wiki lump mechanical information for both games into the same articles. However: I am currently playing Warband.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- You will receive 75% of your army's upkeep as a base payment.
- +3% extra payment per point of Persuasion your character has. (Limit +30%)
- +1% extra payment for every 20 renown your character has. (Limit +40%)
- +15 denars per level for each hero in the party above level 4.

Source [Warband Mercenary](https://www.mejoress.com/en/mount-and-blade-warband-mercenary-contracts/)